# Как посчитать количество объектов с определенным тегом в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет, нужна помощь в решении проблемы, т.к. еще школьник, только учусь. В общем, суть такая: Есть сцена, на ней кубы, Игрок-шар, управляется на W,A,S,D или стрелки, при соприкосновении с кубом тот уничтожается и увеличивает переменную с количеством кубов на 1. Когда переменная достигает одного значения, то сцена переключается. Главным образом проблема состоит в том, что пересоздавать один и тот же скрипт только чтобы поменять одну цифру не рационально, поэтому нужно в if(countCube==) После == поставить универсальное решение, которое собирает количество объектов с тегом "cube" и вписывает их туда.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody player;
    int countCube=0; 
    public Text countText;
    void Start () {
    }
    void Update () {
        player.AddForce (new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0f,Input.GetAxis("Vertical")), ForceMode.Impulse);
        if (countCube==4){
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
        }
        countText.text = "Cubes Collected: " + countCube;
        if(player.transform.position.y<-5){
            SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name);
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        if (other.tag == "cube") {
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
            countCube++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: так а что надо то? найти объекты по тегу это `GameObject.FindGameObectsWithTag("[tag]");`

Comment: ну и это в массивчик записываешь

Comment: Огромное спасибо, сразу не догадался, что надо в массив записать. А чтобы он выдавал конечное число, после приравнивания переменной к которому сцена менялась нужно что с массивом сделать? Вынуть оттуда последний символ? Или как?

Comment: объясни поподробней, я это *А чтобы он выдавал конечное число, после приравнивания переменной к которому сцена менялась нужно что с массивом сделать?* вообще не понял

Comment: Снова привет, уже проблемы  особой нету, но все еще нужна помощь. Можно мне строчку(и) кода, которые преобразуют количество объектов в массив?

Comment: если ты про поиск всех объектов с тегом, то у тебя должен быть массив, например `GameObject _cubes` и просто присвиваешь ему тот метод `_cubes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("tag");` . И попробуй сделать то же самое с листом `List<GameObject> _cubes` . Не знаю как работает с ним

Comment: Ага, спасибо, пока вроде понимаю

Comment: погоди у меня ошибка... вместо `GameObject _cubes` нужно `GameObject[] _cubes`

Comment: Суть в том, что никак не могу понять, почему функции типа pop или lenth не работают, хотя я создал массив по твоему примеру, пишу _cubes. и в подсказках нету, если пишу вручную пишет ошибку

Comment: 1. Подключены ли у тебя библиотеки. 2. Pop() метод для стека. 3. Стоит ли у тебя [], потому что я сначала скинул без скобок.

Comment: 1. Какие именно 2. Что такое стек. 3. да, это я и так знаю

Comment: 1. стандартные при создании скрипта(Collections и Collections.Generic) 2. [Stack](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.8.php). Только что проверял, array.Length работает у меня

Comment: 1 подключены. Так как мне забрать последний число элементов массива?

Comment: `array[array.Length - 1)`. С листом так же, только через `array.Count`

Comment: А для чего после array.Length пишется минус 1? А скобки так и должны быть:слева квадратная, справа круглая?

Comment: скобка должна быть квадратная. минус 1 нужен для того, чтобы не было ошибки OutOfBounds, т.к. с помощью Length мы получаем количесво элементов(например массив из { 1, 2, 3 }. тут три элемента, но отсчет идет с нуля)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что происходит в комментариях? Зачем писать столько комментариев, если можно перейти в чат. Отвечаю на все вопросы.

1. Метод [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) возвращает [массив](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)) всех элементов сцены с указанным тегом. Это нужно присовить переменной с типом данных GameObject[].
2. Чтобы узнать длину массива используем поле Length: `название_массива.Length`
3. Для того чтобы получить последний элемент массива почти всегда используется конструкция получения элемента с индексом (длина массива - 1). Почему? Представим массив строк (слева - индексы элементов, справа - значения)

0 - "Hello"

1 - "World"

2 - "How"

3 - "Are"

4 - "You"

Допустим, нужно получить элемент You. Длина массива 5 элементов, однако мы не можем получить 5-й элемент, т.к. послдений - 4-й (нумерация начинается с 0). Поэтому для получения последнего элемента делаем `название_массива[название_массива.Length - 1]`

> Для получение предпоследнего элемента вычитаем 2, предпредпоследнего вычитаем 3 и т.д. Но обычно приходится получать последний элемент, поэтому вычитаем 1.

[Скобки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) пользователь Methort указал неверно, о чем в последствии написал: они должны быть квадратные, т.к. элемент массива получается с помощью квадратных скобок. Круглые используются в программировании в основном при указании аргументов [функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) в

- самой функции (перечисление нужных аргументов)
- при вызове функции (задание аргументов).

Если остались еще вопросы, задавайте! Если мой ответ был вам полезен, пожалуйста, примите его, поставив галочку.

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!!!!

Comment: Опять не могу разобраться... Массив есть, только вот что мне делать с myArr[myArr.Lenth-1]? Что дальше написать?

Comment: Length, а не Lenth. Это вернет вам последний элемент массива. Желайте с ним что хотите, присвойте в переменную, получите и измените компонент и так далее. Это такая де ссылка на объект, как если бы вы создали переменную GameObject и указали бы какой-то объект